# how to disable the windows address bar

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

I'm securing a certain file, and I cannot do so when the address bar is sitting in the file explorer. How do I disable it. I'm using windows xp. If possible I want it to be disable using regedit or gpedit, but I don't know how. I've already disable folder options using regedit so the option for hiding address bar in folder options is void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it by unchecking `View > Toolbars > Address Bar` in the Explorer menu.